# Laravel 8: Eloquent Query Does Seem To Showing Retrieved Data From the Db

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop basic online ordering system and currently I have a table named `orders` and each order can have one of these statuses:

`suspending`, `awaiting`, `verified`, `confirmed`, `ignored`, and `rejected`.

So at the Controller, I coded this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $uid = auth()->user()->id;
        $suspendeds = Order::where('status', 'suspending')->where('user_id', $uid)->latest()->paginate(2);
        $awaitings = Order::where('status', 'awaiting')->where('user_id', $uid)->latest()->paginate(2);
        $verified = Order::where('status', 'verified')->where('user_id', $uid)->latest()->paginate(2);
        $confirmed = Order::where('status', 'confirmed')->where('user_id', $uid)->latest()->paginate(2);
        $canceled = Order::whereIn('status', ['rejected','ignored'])->where('user_id', $uid)->latest()->paginate(2);
        return view('profile.index', compact(['suspendeds','awaitings','verified','confirmed','canceled']));
    }
```

And then at the Blade, I added this:

```
<div class="profile-body BKoodakBold">
      @include('profile.orders.suspends')
      @include('profile.orders.awaites')
      @include('profile.orders.verifies')
      @include('profile.orders.confirms')
      @include('profile.orders.cancels')
</div>
```

And each Blade, follow the same structure just like this:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($verified as $verify)
    <tr>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ $verify->title }}" disabled="disabled"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ $verify->material }}" disabled="disabled"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ $verify->color }}" disabled="disabled"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control"type="text" value="{{ $verify->description }}" disabled="disabled"></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

But now the problem is, it does not show anything at all! However, there are many Orders available at `orders` table, following those specific statuses that I have written earlier.

And also if I `dd()` each variable at the Controller method, it will prints the data successfully on page, meaning that the queries are working fine.

So what is going wrong here? How can I show data properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide variables to child views

```
  @include('profile.orders.suspends', ['suspends' => $suspends])
  @include('profile.orders.awaites', ['awaites' => $awaites])
  @include('profile.orders.verifies', ['verifies' => $verifies])
  @include('profile.orders.confirms', ['confirms' => $confirms])
  @include('profile.orders.cancels', ['cancels' => $cancels])
```

Comment: you can just pass the variable `  @include('profile.orders.suspends', $suspends)`